# Perl regex wrongfully evaluating expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following perl code with a string that I'm needing to check against several cases in order to decide what to do with it.  None of them work.  Code looks like this:

```
my $param = "02 1999";
my @months = qw(january february march april may june july august september october november december);

my $white = /^\s*$/; #check if all whitespace
my $singleyear = /^\d{2,4}$/; #check if 2-4 digits
my $nummonth = /^\d{1,2}\s\d{1,4}$/; #check if 1-2 digits then 1-4

if ($param =~ $white) {
    my($day, $month, $year)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
    my $monthname = $months[$month]; 
    print "$monthname $year\n";
}
if ($param =~ $singleyear) {
    print "$param\n";
}
if ($param =~ $nummonth) {
    my $monthnumber = $param =~ /^\d{1,2}/; #grabs the number at the front of the string
    my $monthstring = $months[$monthnumber]; 
    my $yearnumber = $param =~ /(\d{1,4})$/; #grab second number, it does this wrong
    print "$monthstring $yearnumber\n";
}
```

Given the above, the output should simply be:

```
february 1999
```

Instead, the output is:

```
3 118
02 1999
february 1 #this only grabbed the first digit for some reason.
```

So ALL of the cases evaluated as true for some reason, and the capture on the year didn't even work. What am I doing wrong?  Testing all of my regex at regex101 worked fine, but not in the script.

Comment: Your code contains several syntax errors. Fix those first, then enable `use strict; use warnings;` and try again.

Comment: `my $yearnumber = $param =~ /(\d{1,4})$/;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Nor does `my $white = /^\s*$/;` but I find it hard to explain things properly with code that doesn't even parse, let alone pass `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: @melpomene I mostly transcribed over to this post from my code for formatting reasons, I apologize for any typos.  It runs without error where I'm executing it, ironically with `strict` and `warnings`.  I fixed a couple missing semicolons in the post.

Comment: @melpomene I included the months array

Comment: Your code doesn't pass `strict` (undeclared variables, missing `$`). Once you fix that, you'll see a (hopefully) helpful warning.

Comment: @melpomene more syntax edits

Comment: @user3066571 OK, now what do you think about the warning you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues that are central to your question.

First, you apparently want to save precompiled regexes in the variables `$white`, `$singleyear`, and `$nummonth`, but you are not using the right operator for that - you should use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qr/_STRING_/msixpodualn) to compile and save the regex. Code like `my $white = /^\s*$/;` will *run* the regex against [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_) and store the *result* in `$white`.

Second, `my $monthnumber = $param =~ /^\d{1,2}/;` has two issues: the [`=~` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) used with [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m/_PATTERN_/msixpodualngc) in scalar context simply returns a true/false value (that's the `1` you're seeing in the output `february 1`), but if you want to get the capture groups from the regex, you need to use it in list context, in this case by saying `my ($monthnumber) = ...` (the same issue applies to `$yearnumber`). Second, that regex doesn't contain any capture groups!

I don't get exactly the output you claim (although it's close) - please have a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially since your post initially contained quite a few syntax errors. If I apply the fixes I described above, I get the output

```
march 1999
```

which is what I would expect - I hope you can figure out how to fix the off-by-one error.

*Update:* I should add that you also don't need to try and parse date/times yourself. My favorite module for date/time handling is [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) (together with [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime)), but in this case the core [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is enough:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $param = "02 1999";
my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($param, "%m %Y");
print $dt->fullmonth, " ", $dt->year, "\n";       # prints "February 1999"
```